# Transition for progress element on value change

Tags: css, progress-bar, css-transitions

I am trying to add a transition to the `progress` element using CSS, so that when the value of it changes, it will move the progress bar inside the container smoothly. What I am having trouble with is getting the transition to work at all and I have no idea where to put such a transition, as there is nothing like `:hover` for example when the value changes (not that I know of). **So is what I am trying to do even possible and, if so, how?**

Code snippet below:

```css
progress {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  border: 0;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1px auto;
  height: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  transition: all 5s ease 0; /* Does not work */
}
  progress[value]::-webkit-progress-value {
    background: red;
    transition: all 5s ease 0; /* Does not work */
  }
  progress[value]::-webkit-progress-bar {
    background: yellow;
    transition: all 5s ease 0; /* Does not work */
  }
  progress[value]::-moz-progress-bar {
    background: red;
    transition: all 5s ease 0; /* Does not work */
  }
```

```html
<h3>Progress bar with transition</h3>
<progress id="test-prog" value="25" max="100"></progress>
  <br>
   <button onclick="document.getElementById('test-prog').setAttribute('value',parseInt(document.getElementById('test-prog').getAttribute('value'))+5);">Click me to see the progress bar value change</button>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can give `transition` to the value of `<progress>` element.

It's being drawn via the operating system, and not via CSS (that's why it looks different in different operating systems - like the scroll bar).

If you want, you can implement your own HTML+CSS progress bar, and give it transitions.

Example: http://codepen.io/mcraiganthony/pen/waaeWO

Comment: I have used custom CSS progress bar implementations in the past using `<div>` and CSS and they work properly. However, I want to try animating the default `<progress>` element.

Comment: @AngelosChalaris Then I am afraid it cannot be done, or it will not be easy to implement cross browser / cross operating systems.

Comment: An working example: https://codepen.io/snookca/pen/KRdRzZ

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question but I found a way to animate value change in chrome using

```css
::-webkit-progress-value {
  transition: width 1s;
}
```

Source: [Animating Progress](https://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/animating-progress)

Comment: Four and a half years later, this is now the correct answer!

Comment: Also: In order to let ::-webkit-progress-value take effect, appearance needs to be set to none on the <progress> element. As explained here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-progress-value